# Is there a way to run a default code in Jupyter Notebook without using %load or setting a profile?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to integrate jupyter as a testing playground to an existing python framework. The framework requires a set of python statements to execute in order to initialise and connect to database before actual testing can begin.

So, it there a way to pass a set of default execution statements whenever a new Notebook is spawned in browser?

- This has to be completely automatic.
- User doesn't need to know that there's this file that you need to load.
- It shouldn't clutter their user directory.
- Complete code should be displayed in the first cell, and executed whenever new browser window starts, or kernel is reloaded.

Is there a way to do this?

Edit: Found the proper solution.

```
ipython -i <path_to_python_file>
```

This could be integrated in the framework to be seamless and will not require user to manually maintain anything in their user directory.

Comment: Actually launching a notebook as part of a test for something else doesn't seem like a great idea. You should consider mocking it. Look at the `mock` module.

Comment: Add startup scripts in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`. There is a `README` file there to teach you.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev This is not really a duplicate. Other answers only provide how to manually load from a file or add to profile. I want something like running a python script and then Embedding I-Python console. But in jupyter.

Comment: @coldspeed please see above comment